# How to implement "close all tabs" for tabcontrol

Tags: c#, windows

How would I implement "close all other tabs" function for a tab control using Context menu strip?

Comment: This is a dup of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301116/how-to-handle-close-other-tabs-in-contextmenustrip

Comment: Since neither had replies, I closed the later of the two

Answer (score 3):

I made a small app with just one tabcontrol in the main window and a context menu connected to that tabcontrol.

The following is the handler for the context menu item:

```
        private void closeAllOtherToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
            if (i != tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
                tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(i--);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple Code to "Close all tabs".

```
tabControl.TabPages.Clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code closes all tabs and before closing it makes sure that the content of tabs gets saved.

```
    private void closeAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl.TabPageCollection pages = tabControl1.TabPages;
        foreach (TabPage page in pages)
        {
            saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
            closeTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you "close all" your tabs, you should dispose (and remove event handlers) of any controls/objects you had instantiated in each tab page.  Also, you can use the .Clear method of the TabPages collection instead of removing each tab page in a loop.